# SQL Server query performance issue using synonyms

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to check synonym table records against my database table.

The following statement works fine for me, but I would like to get rid of insert and temporary table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_table') IS NOT NULL
     DROP TABLE #tmp_table

SELECT 
    id 
INTO
    #tmp_table
FROM
    synonyms_table WITH (nolock)  
WHERE
    created_date BETWEEN GETDATE() - 4 AND GETDATE() - 1 

SELECT id
FROM #tmp_table tmp    
LEFT JOIN main_table main WITH (NOLOCK) ON tmp.id COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = main.id
WHERE main.id IS NULL
```

The problem is, both tables are huge and if I am going to use left join or not exist, it is going to be very slow:

```
SELECT id 
FROM synonyms_table sy WITH (NOLOCK) 
LEFT JOIN main_table main WITH (NOLOCK) ON sy.id COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = main.id
WHERE sy.created_date BETWEEN GETDATE() - 4 AND GETDATE() - 1 
  AND main.id IS NULL
```

Maybe someone here knows a good solutions for me :)

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of temp table if that's working fine?

Comment: I'd stop using `getdate()-4` and start using `DateAdd()` explicitly for clarity and to prevent errors later on. And why not just join to the synonyms_table directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, bearing in mind that the optimiser might decide to run an execution plan that goes back to the non-performant version:

```
WITH Base AS (
    SELECT 
        id COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS id
    FROM 
        synonyms_table WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE
        created_date BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -4, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()))
SELECT
    id
FROM
    Base b
    LEFT JOIN main_table main WITH (NOLOCK) ON b.id = main.id
WHERE 
    main.id IS NULL;
```

One of your overheads is the collation, so I pre-collate the data in the common-table expression.

Answer (score 1):

If  your goal is to get records from synonyms table that do not exists in main table, you should use `NOT EXISTS`. It should perform better, but you won't know until you try.

```
SELECT Id
FROM synonyms_table s
WHERE s.created_date BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -4, GETDATE()) 
    AND DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()))
AND NOT EXISTS 
(
   SELECT * FROM main_table m 
   WHERE m.Id = s.Id COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
)
```

But, if the #temp table solution is working better, I would definitely keep it. In fact I would suggest two improvements that could further enhance performance with it.

1) Instead of using COLLATE in join (that's expensive), you can create your temp table with correct collation by adding COLLATE to SELECT INTO

```
SELECT id COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS Id  
INTO #tmp_table
FROM synonyms_table
```

2) Create clustered index on temp table after creating it and before joining

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_tmp_table ON #tmp_table (Id)
```